# IDE "can't resolve" obvious variable

Tags: c++, clion

as you already read, my IDE (CLion from JetBrains) "can't resolve" a variable. Here's my code:

```
template <typename T>
class List<T>::Iterator {
    friend class List;
    _Item** _current; //_Item private struct in class List
public:
    inline T& operator* () const;
};

template <typename T>
inline T& List<T>::Iterator::operator* () const {
    if (! _current)
        throw std::invalid_argument("List::Iterator::operator*: singular value");
    if (! *_current)
        throw std::invalid_argument("List::Iterator::operator*: end() value");
    return (*_current)->info;
}`
```

**_current** is the variable that CLion "can't resolve" in `inline T& operator* () const;`

I already tried to invalidate cache and restart.
My code compile. The IDE should be the problem. I even got in a method this message from my IDE:

> "Returning 'Iterator' from a function returning 'Iterator'. Class
>   'Iterator' not compatible with class 'Iterator'

Comment: Is that a compilation error? If so, please post a full error message, as well as compiler name and version. Also, FYI, names starting with `_` followed by an uppercase letter are reserved and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Thx for the comment and the info.
No, my code compile. The IDE should be the problem. I even got the message: "Returning 'Iterator' from a function returning 'Iterator'. Class 'Iterator' not compatible with class 'Iterator'
I'll edit my post to add those informations

Comment: @dragonfire2000 Seems like an IDE bug. Try contacting CLion support maybe?

Comment: i just sent an email